# Nginx 301 Redirect

Tags: redirect, nginx, permanent

I have website with permalink like this this:

_http://www.domain.com/read/o/one-url-posting/

_http://www.domain.com/read/t/two-url-posting/

_http://www.domain.com/read/f/four-url-posting/

_http://www.domain.com/read/s/six-url-posting/

_http://www.domain.com/read/n/nine-url-posting/

_http://www.domain.com/read/x/xxx-url-posting/

How to redirect all permalink to _http://www.domain.com/read/nine-url-posting/ without one char between slash after "read" slug?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer from another web, like this.

```
location ~ ^/read/(.*)/(.*)/ {    
    return 301 /read/$2/;    
}
```

Case closed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you need all links rewrited to 1 link or each link to same link, but without one char (x/xxx-url-posting/ -> xxx-url-posting/)?

Try this for first case:

```
rewrite "^/read/([a-z]{1})/(.*)/$" /read/nine-url-posting/ last;
```

And this for second case:

```
rewrite "^/read/([a-z]{1})/(.*)/$" /read/$2/ last;
```